# Scala refined: concatenating NonEmptyStrings

Tags: scala, refined

I'm using the [`NonEmptyString`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/eu.timepit/refined_2.13/0.10.2/eu/timepit/refined/types/StringTypes.html#NonEmptyString=eu.timepit.refined.types.string.NonEmptyString) type from the refined library. When concatenating two strings, at least one of which is non-empty, the result is obviously another non-empty string. But is there a way to convince the Scala compiler of this fact without using unsafe methods such as `NonEmptyString.unsafeFrom`?

Comment: Not really AFAIK, the best you can do is create your own extension methods so that the cast is done in one place only.

Comment: https://github.com/fthomas/refined/issues/217

Comment: https://gist.github.com/notthatbreezy/ed9fb4fa5edc066bf7706d8b8333cdd2#scala-practical-guide